# How does SQL choose which row to show when grouping multiple rows together?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
 a INTEGER NOT NULL,
 b INTEGER NOT NULL,
 c INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
)
```

Now if I do this:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM t GROUP BY a;
```

I expect to have get each distinct value of a only once. But since I'm asking for b and c as well, it's going to give me a row for every value of a. Therefor, if, for a single value of a, there are many rows to choose from, how can I predict which row SQL will choose? My tests show that it chooses to return the row for which b is the greatest. But what is the logic in that? How would this apply to strings of blobs or dates or anything else?

My question: How does SQL choose which row to show when grouping multiple rows together?

btw: My particular problem concerns SQLITE3, but I'm guessing this is an SQL issue not dependent of the DBMS...

Comment: In some SQL RDBMSs, the query you've shown is illegal, so there isn't a pure "SQL" answer. And in most places in SQL, if no ORDER BY clause is in effect, the system is free to reorder its outputs as it sees fit.

Comment: It is dependent on RDBMS. For example, SQL Server would flag your SELECT statement as an error.

Comment: feels like broken syntax, there has to be a better way to get the data you need using a "standard" SQL statement.  Maybe you need to break this into multiple queries...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually, ordering my data doesn't change anything (in my particular case) to the outcome. I've tried it many many times and it always chooses the same row...

Comment: but it's one of those things that isn't guaranteed. It's been true in all of your tests today, but could be completely different tomorrow. Or if you upgrade. Or if there's more memory pressure on the system. Basically, there's NO *guarantee*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That shouldn't actually work in a decent DBMS :-)

Any column not used in the `group by` clause should be subject to an aggregation function, such as:

```
select a, max(b), sum(c) from t group by a
```

*If* it doesn't complain in SQLite (and I have no immediate reason to doubt you), I'd just put it down to the way the DBMS is built. From memory, there's a few areas where it doesn't worry too much about the "purity" of the data (such as every column being able to hold multiple types, the type belonging to the data in that row/column intersect rather than the column specification).

Comment: And the aggregation function will thus dictate which rows are shown for the other value, i.e. SELECT a, max(b), min(c) FROM t GROUP BY a

Answer (score 2):

All the SQL engines that I know will complain about the query that you mentioned with an error message like "b and c appear in the field list but not in the group by list". You are only allowed to use b or c in an aggregate function (like MAX / MIN / COUNT / AVG whatever) or you'll be forced to add them in the GROUP BY list.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quite correct about your assumption that this is RDBMS-independent. Most RDBMS don't allow to select fields that are not also in the `GROUP BY` clause. Exceptions to this (to my knowledge) are SQLite and MySQL. In general, you shouldn't do this, because values for `b` and `c` are chosen pretty arbitrarily (depending on the applied grouping algorithm). Even if this may be documented in your database, it's always better to express a query in a way that fully and non-ambiguously specifies the outcome

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of what the database will choose, but the order your data are going to be returned.

Your primary key is handling your sort order by default since you didn't provide one.

You can use Order By a, c if that's what you want.

Comment: Actually, ordering my data doesn't change anything (in my particular case) to the outcome. I've tried it many many times and it always chooses the same row...